# What character encoding are URLs supposed to be in?

Tags: http, url, character-encoding

I've seen some browsers encode (for example) é as %E9 (ISO-8859-1) or %C3%A9 (UTF-8) and I'm not sure which one is correct. Is there a way to see what encoding that the request is intended to be interpreted as?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URI scheme decides how the URI should be encoded.

For *new* URI schemes, UTF-8 is [recommended](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2718#section-2.2.5):

> Unless there is some compelling reason for a particular scheme to do otherwise, translating character sequences into UTF-8 (RFC 2279) and then subsequently using the `%HH` encoding for unsafe octets is recommended.

`http` and `https` do not specify how URIs should be encoded.

For IRIs, the corresponding URI [has to be](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3987#section-1.2) encoded in UTF-8:

> The URI corresponding to the IRI in question has to encode original characters into octets using UTF-8.

Answer (score 3):

No. It's entirely up to the server to decide how to encode non-ASCII characters. Unfortunately.